# php function for mySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

this is my first ajax function that I am calling on from another page that sends a single array which is 9 entries of an integer over the $_POST.

The table has three rows (an ID increment, another called listnum, and another for a url).
Listnum is "the order" that the URLS should be displayed. So this script is intended to update the order per the NEW order that is delivered from POST. In other words listnum 1 would get its URL overwritted with a new URL and all the others would adjust up or down to keep the total number of list items the same with no null fields. Hope that's not too convoluted.

Something has gone amiss though and there's only so much trial and error I can do... been at at for a few hours now. Though some seasoned eyes might have a thing or two to say.

```
<?
$gotfrompost[] = $_REQUEST[fruitarray];

$con = mysql_connect("dasdfasdft","dbasdfasdf04","noasdfasdfs");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("db337100104", $con); 

$row_total_count  = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `vim_playlist4`");

// above value should be 9 (as it happens)

$n = 1;

while ($row_total_count > $n) 
{

mysql_select_db("db337100104", $con); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vim_playlist4 WHERE listnum=$gotfrompost[$n]");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
     $new_url_array[$n] =  $row['url'] ;
     $n++;
  }
}


mysql_select_db("db337100104", $con);   

mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE vim_playlist4");

$a = 1;

while($row_total_count > $a){

mysql_query("INSERT INTO vim_playlist4 (url, listnum)
VALUES ('$new_url_array[$a]', '$a')");  

$a++; 

}
  ?>
```

Thank you so much for your time, and hopefully this will be a no-brainer for some of you veteran phpers

Comment: Hi Will, you probably learnt about `mysql_*` functions from an outdated tutorial or book. They are deprecated and shouldn't be used. I highly recommended reading up about PDO. It's easy to learn the basics and it will make your code faster and less vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, which you may want to read about as well.

Comment: You should use quotes around the string fruitarray: `$_REQUEST['fruitarray'];`. That won't fix your problem, but there are a lot of good reasons to never leave those quotes out.

Comment: You should also use `$_POST` when trying to read information from POST. `$_REQUEST` includes cookies and GET parameters and depending on your configuration the `GET` variables could be overriding `POST` ones.

Comment: There is no need to `mysql_select_db` before every query. Unless you are switching from one database to another you only need to select the database once.

Comment: Also emptying the whole table and then reinserting everything is not the right way to go about this. You should be using `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: Nice [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Marc B Thanks for the heads up! 
And Paulpro, thanks for tunring me on to the update query. I'll check that out tomorrow. All this tough love truth is great, keep it coming

Comment: Actually, first thing tomorrow I am going to look up PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Like other people already mentioned, please do not use `mysql_*` since it exposes you to sql-injection (use MySQLi or PDO instead).

You should [*test your input*](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) from that exact same reason!

Another issue you have there is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vim_playlist4 WHERE listnum=$gotfrompost[$n]");
```

should be changed to:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vim_playlist4 WHERE listnum={$gotfrompost[$n]}");
```